# comparing row wise each values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My data frame looks like (almost 10M) -

```
date          value1       value2
01/02/2019       10           120
02/02/2019       21           130
03/02/2019       0            140
04/02/2019       24           150
05/02/2019       29           160
06/02/2019       32           160 
07/02/2019       54           160
08/02/2019       32           180
01/02/2019       -3           188
```

My final output looks like -

```
date          value1       value2      result
01/02/2019       10           120        1
02/02/2019       21           130        1
03/02/2019       0            140        0
04/02/2019       24           150        1
05/02/2019       29           160        1
06/02/2019       32           160        0
07/02/2019       54           160        0
08/02/2019       32           180        1
01/02/2019      -3            188        0
```

My logic should if value1 <=0 or 3 consecutive rows(value2) is same then result is 0 otherwise 1

How to do it in pandas

Comment: Can you explain more the concept of the 3 consecutive rows? for example, where `value1` is 29 there are 3 consecutive rows where `value2` is 160, but the result is 1.

Comment: Could you explain the logic a bit more ?

Comment: @jcaliz and@sajan - 3 consecutive rows is present in 5,6,7.my log is if value1<0 then 0 or if no difference exist in 3 consecutive rows then result is 0, otherwise 1.

Comment: Then why row 5 (row 4 if 0-indexed)  haas results as 1 if its part of three consecutives 160s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try, defining your own function that handles consecutive values, and where `value1` is above 0, then `groupby` using a custom series of consecutives and finally apply the custom function:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = '''date,value1,value2
01/02/2019,10,120
02/02/2019,21,130
03/02/2019,0,140
04/02/2019,24,150
05/02/2019,29,160
06/02/2019,32,160
07/02/2019,54,160
08/02/2019,32,180
01/02/2019,-3,188'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=0, index_col=0)


def fun(group_df):
    if group_df.shape[0] >= 3:
        return pd.Series([0]*group_df.shape[0], index=group_df.index)
    else:
        return group_df.value1 > 0


consecutives = (df.value2 != df.value2.shift()).cumsum()
df['results'] = df.groupby(consecutives).apply(
    fun).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

In this case `fun` is a vectorized function to check if consectives are 3 or more, or if values are greater than 0, the results are:

```
print(df)
#            value1 value2  results
# date          
# 01/02/2019    10  120   1
# 02/02/2019    21  130   1
# 03/02/2019    0   140   0
# 04/02/2019    24  150   1
# 05/02/2019    29  160   0
# 06/02/2019    32  160   0
# 07/02/2019    54  160   0
# 08/02/2019    32  180   1
# 01/02/2019    -3  188   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this
`np.where((df.value1.le(0)) | (df.value2.diff().eq(0)), 0, 1)`